# xml_nodeset (0), trying to webscrape data table

Tags: html, web-scraping, rvest

I'm attempting to webscrape "https://www.rotowire.com/betting/nba/archive.php" and just get the data from the data table present.
[image]

The code I have so far:

```
rm(list=ls())
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

url <- read_html("https://www.rotowire.com/betting/nba/archive.php")
test <- url %>% html_nodes("body") %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="datatable1681315996838"]')
test <- url %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="datatable1681315996838"]') %>% html_table()
```

But I keep getting a {xml_nodeset (0)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the data is loaded after the page is loaded, hence why rvest isn't working. The page appears to make a request to https://www.rotowire.com/betting/nba/tables/games-archive.php, so we can perform this request manually using `httr2` (or `httr`, if you prefer).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(httr2)

response <- request("https://www.rotowire.com/betting/nba/tables/games-archive.php") %>%
  req_perform()

url <- response %>%
  resp_body_json()

as_tibble(transpose(url)) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), \(x) list_c(x)))
#> # A tibble: 7,454 × 25
#>    season game_date   game_time home_team_id home_team_stats_id home_team_abbrev
#>    <chr>  <chr>       <chr>     <chr>        <chr>              <chr>           
#>  1 2017   2017-10-17… 20        11           CLE                CLE             
#>  2 2017   2017-10-17… 22        22           GSW                GSW             
#>  3 2017   2017-10-18… 19        12           DET                DET             
#>  4 2017   2017-10-18… 19        29           IND                IND             
#>  5 2017   2017-10-18… 19        5            ORL                ORL             
#>  6 2017   2017-10-18… 19        7            WAS                WAS             
#>  7 2017   2017-10-18… 19        2            BOS                BOS             
#>  8 2017   2017-10-18… 20        21           MEM                MEM             
#>  9 2017   2017-10-18… 20        15           DAL                DAL             
#> 10 2017   2017-10-18… 21        20           UTA                UTA             
#> # ℹ 7,444 more rows
#> # ℹ 19 more variables: visit_team_id <chr>, visit_team_stats_id <chr>,
#> #   visit_team_abbrev <chr>, home_team_score <int>, visit_team_score <int>,
#> #   game_over_under <chr>, line <dbl>, tipoff <chr>, month <chr>, start <chr>,
#> #   favorite <chr>, score <chr>, total <int>, spread <dbl>, over_hit <int>,
#> #   under_hit <int>, favorite_covered <int>, underdog_covered <int>, name <chr>
```

Comment: Thanks Ashby that's perfect! Thank you!